# why am I getting the warning excess initializers are ignored?

Tags: c, arrays

I have initialized an array as follows:

```
#define WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE   426
unsigned char writebuffer[WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
};
```

In the above, though the number of elements within the array I have initialized is equal to 426, yet why is the compiler throwing a warning saying **excess initializers are ignored**. I don't want any samples/elements within the array to be ignored.

Comment: Are you *sure* there are no more than 426 numbers in the initializer? And why not simply let the compiler fix it by using no size at all, e.g. `unsigned char writebuffer[] = { ... }`? You can still get the number of elements by using `sizeof`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/DkC6wV There's no problem in here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is do my job for me post.

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I bet your initialize-list contains more than 426 items.

Comment: That is because you have 434 initialisers.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, "Do my job for me"? It's a clear question about a concise code fragment the OP fails to understand. It's what SO *is for*!

Comment: @StoryTeller fails to understand? what? The first job was to count the number of elements in the init-list, see the answer. We're certainly not here to count the elements which OP should have done at least before posting the question.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the OP obviously miscounted, that buffer size is too arbitrary to be anything other than the OP's count. Then they didn't understand why their count was wrong, so they asked how to reason about the warning. That, is a good question. And now it has a good answer for posterity.

Comment: @StoryTeller I beg to differ, there's an explicit close-vote reason for typo-related error. this is nothing but typo, note OP already said _"though the number of elements within the array I have initialized is equal to 426"_

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the typo clause also specifies *"was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"*, which is not the case here. And I noted and reasoned about what the OP said, thank you.

Comment: @StoryTeller compiler tells me something about "excess initializers".. ok, so I go and count the number of initializers first. I fail to see how a miscount leads to a good question. Oh, and did I miss a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=excess+initializers+are+ignored&oq=excess+initializers+are+ignored&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, so what is it? A dup, a typo, or just a "I'm in a bad temper, so I'll close with a rude reason"?

Comment: @StoryTeller it's just a "Do my job for me", a lazy attempt. You're welcome to have a different angle, we respect that, and I guess I am allowed to have my own viewpoint, too, without being rude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are initializing your array with 434 elements (but it is declared as an array of 426), use `sizeof` (without defining the dimension in the array) to check this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char writebuffer[] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
    };

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof writebuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
434
```